# Javascript, image doesn't change while sleep unless run alert() first

Tags: javascript, alert, sleep

I have an Image which changes color when i drop it into a drawn box.

Once one has dropped it into the box, I go to next screen.
But I want there to be a short wait first.

But when I introduce the wait..
the image doesn't change color.. even though it confirms the color changing code has run.

But.. if I set an alert("hi"); before the code that halts the engine.. then the color change takes place before waiting session.

It is as if alert(); is doing something behind the scenes that causes the color change of the div to happen correctly.

How can I force this color change to take place before I run the sleep method?

Kinda like running alert without having to have the alert actually popping up.

Comment: Showing some code would be useful. Alert halts all execution

Comment: There is no "sleep" method in JavaScript. If you're written your own, the problem is almost certainly that you're "busy-waiting" (doing a tight loop, pegging the CPU). You probably want `setTimeout` instead, which schedules something to run at a later time *without* busy-waiting, allowing other things (like, say, changing an image) to happen. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no sleep method, so I am guessing that you are using a while loop for your "sleep". The while loop locks up the browser and prevents the page from updating. The alert adds a slight delay and allows the page to update.

What you need to do is break up your code and use a setTimeout for the "sleep".

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
img.src = "foo.gif";
function nextStep() {
    alert("do your next step here");
}

window.setTimeout(nextStep, 2000); //2 seconds
```